# What are the project settings in SSRS deployment?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdl

I have successfully created my first SSRS project in Visual Studio.  The deployment process requires setting up the TargetServerURL and the TargetServer Version.  These are the only two items that I know are correct.  The tutorial I have been watching does not go into the other items and does not clarify what they are and what they are used for.  What are the following items referring to?

- TargetDatasetFolder
- TargetDataSourceFolder
- TargetReportFolder
- TargetReportPartFolder

The default settings for OverwriteDatasets and OverwriteDataSources was False and this is probably why my deployment attemtp threw a nondescript error.  So, now, perhaps if I try again, my deployment will create these folders on the server by force, but I owuld rather not do this because the database manager has already given me the names of the folders where I should deploy.  So, how are these Folders arranged?  Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- TargetDataSourceFolder: The name of the folder in which to store the published shared data sources. If you do not specify a folder, the data source is published to the same folder as the report. If the folder does not exist on the report server, Report Designer creates the folder when the reports are published.
- TargetDataSetFolder: the same but for your shared data set you want to publish.
- TargetReportFolder: The name of the folder in which to store the published reports. By default, this is the name of the report project. If the folder does not exist on the report server, Report Designer creates the folder when the reports are published.

You can write a path (finance/dept1/...) in this case, you'll deploy your report (or datasets or datasources) following this path.

Here is an exemple by default from microsoft: [image]

About 'overwrite dataset' and 'overwrite datasource' (it's about 'shared dataset' and 'shared datasource') it depends on the architecture you chose (or if you have already something created) on the server.

I think the best way is to let them as False. If they don't exist, the deployment will create them. If they exist, you'll just get a warning (if I remember) and the report you'll be deploying should link your report to those dataset and datasource already created. Futhermore, probably you have other reports linked to those shared datasource/dataset and if you overwrite them, you'll probably raise some issues when you'll run those other reports. You have to put 'True' when you want to modify the dataset/datasource

Comment: Overwrite dataset/datasource should always be left False. Your reports on your development system should point to a development database while the deployed reports will be configured on the report server to point to the production database. You don't want this overwritten by the dev settings when deploying reports.